# react-native-svg-uri can not apply translate in svg file (svg in map as marker in react native)

Tags: react-native

I want show svg file as marker in react native google map.
I used react-native-svg-uri but this library can not work well.
What should I do?

icon.svg is :

[image]

svg code :

```
<svg width="57.275" height="17.05" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0.775,0.5)" origin-transform="translate(0.7749999999999986 0.5)" iid="stand"><path d="m1 1h28v14h-28z" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></path><spot enable="false" uuid="1265" x="28.875" y="1.025" width="6" height="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffa500" style=""></spot><spot enable="false" uuid="1266" x="15.125" y="1.4" width="6" height="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffa500" style=""></spot><spot enable="false" uuid="1267" x="1.125" y="0.8999999999999999" width="6" height="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffa500" style=""></spot><spot enable="false" uuid="1268" x="0.625" y="8.15" width="6" height="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffa500" style=""></spot><spot enable="false" uuid="1269" x="0.875" y="15.15" width="6" height="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffa500" style=""></spot><spot enable="false" uuid="1270" x="15.125" y="15.15" width="6" height="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffa500" style=""></spot><spot enable="false" uuid="1271" x="28.875" y="15.15" width="6" height="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffa500" style=""></spot><spot enable="false" uuid="1272" x="29" y="8.4" width="6" height="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffa500" style=""></spot></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,29.275,3.375)" origin-transform="translate(29.275,↵                                 3.375)↵                                 rotate(0, 0.5, 5.525)" uuid="undefined" zirtajhizId="2385" kalaTypeId="1" vaziyatKala="0"><path d="m0 5 17-2" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="2"></path><path d="m28 5.5c0 .9664979-.68341637 1.79145575-2.05025291 2.47487354-1.36683655.68341828-3.01675034 1.02512741-4.94974709 1.02512646-1.93299484.00000095-3.58291054-.34170818-4.94974709-1.02512646-1.36683464-.68341779-2.05025291-1.50837564-2.05025291-2.47487402.00000095-.96649885.68341827-1.79145646 2.05025291-2.4748733 1.36683274-.68341732 3.01675034-1.02512598 4.94974709-1.02512622 1.93299866.00000024 3.58291435.3417089 4.94974709 1.02512622 1.36683654.6834178 2.05025291 1.50837588 2.05025291 2.47487378z" fill="#fff" stroke="#000"></path></g></svg>
```

my code :

```
  <MapView
  style={{flex: 1}}
  initialRegion={{
    latitude: 29.594155,
    longitude: 52.5463045,
    latitudeDelta: 29.594155,
    longitudeDelta: 52.5463045,
  }}>
  />
  <Marker coordinate={{latitude: 29.626511, longitude: 52.5162953}}>
    <SvgUri source={require('./assets/icon.svg')} />
  </Marker>
</MapView>
```

but result is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this library can help me :

react-native-svg-uri-reborn

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-uri-reborn?activeTab=readme

result :

[image]

but can not apply fill color svg . but you can set fill color with fill param :

`<SvgUri source={require('./assets/icon.svg')}  fill={'white'}/>`

result :

[image]